# Train SVM on a very large dataset stored on hard drive

Tags: r, machine-learning, bigdata, svm, libsvm

There exist a very large own-collected dataset of size **[2000000 12672]** where the rows shows the number of instances and the columns, the number of features. This dataset occupies **~60 Gigabyte** on the local hard disk. I want to train a linear SVM on this dataset. The problem is that I have only **8 Gigabyte of RAM!** so I cannot load all data once. Is there any solution to train the SVM on this large dataset? Generating the dataset is on my own desire, and currently are is HDF5 format.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the `ff` package

Comment: @tguzella the `ff` package is not helpful here.

Comment: @Slater Tyranus Why not?

Comment: @tguzella because the issue is not simply loading the file, but using it in an SVM. If it were just about accessing the file `ff` would be fine, but it's unsuitable for further use in an off-line algorithm.

Comment: @Saeed Is this a regression or classification problem? If classification, how many classes?

Comment: If you can use python - you should use something like [SGDClassifier/regressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier)

It has partial_fit method, with which you can fit the model without loading whole dataset. You just need to load your dataset by chunks and feed it to this partial_fit method. AFAIK Pandas library can load HDF5.

I don't think that it's real problem in python :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stochastic gradient descent approach to SVM could help, as it scales well and avoids the `n^2` problem. An implementation available in R is `RSofia`, which was created by a team at Google and is discussed in [Large Scale Learning to Rank](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/35662.pdf). In the paper, they show that compared to a traditional SVM, the SGD approach significantly decreases the training time (this is due to 1, the pairwise learning method and 2, only a subset of the observations end up being used to train the model).

Note that `RSofia` is a little more bare bones than some of the other SVM packages available in R; for example, you need to do your own centering and scaling of features.

As to your memory problem, it'd be a little surprising if you needed the entire dataset - I would expect that you'd be fine reading in a sample of your data and then training your model on that. To confirm this, you could train multiple models on different samples and then estimate performance on the same holdout set - the performance should be similar across the different models.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to machine learning! One of the hard things about working in this space is the compute requirements. There are two main kinds of algorithms, on-line and off-line.

- Online: supports feeding in examples one at a time, each one improving the model slightly
- Offline: supports feeding in the entire dataset at once, achieving higher accuracy than an On-line model

Many typical algorithms have both on-line, and off-line implementations, but an SVM is not one of them. To the best of my knowledge, SVMs are traditionally an off-line only algorithm. The reason for this is a lot of the fine details around "shattering" the dataset. I won't go too far into the math here, but if you read into it it should become apparent.

It's also worth noting that the complexity of an SVM is somewhere between `n^2` and `n^3`, meaning that even if you could load everything into memory it would take ages to actually train the model. It's very typical to test with a much smaller portion of your dataset before moving to the full dataset.

When moving to the full dataset you would have to run this on a much larger machine than your own, but AWS should have something large enough for you, though at your size of data I highly advise using something other than an SVM. At large data sizes, neural net approaches really shine, and can be trained in a more realistic amount of time.

As alluded to in the comments, there's also the concept of an `out-of-core` algorithm that can operate directly on objects stored on disk. The only group I know with a good offering of out-of-core algorithms is [dato](https://dato.com/). It's a commercial product, but might be your best solution here.

Comment: Well, he explicitly mentioned that he wants to apply a linear SVM, for which the training complexity is lower. For example, see the classic paper by Joachims in KDD 2006 (http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/publications/joachims_06a.pdf)

Comment: @Slater Tyranus Thanks you for your useful notes. I just came across this paper: (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/kdd_disk_decomposition.pdf)
How do you see this paper? Please let me know your comments on this paper. Thanks

Comment: @tguzella I missed that, thanks for mentioning. That said, despite Joachim's paper, the majority of linear SVM implementations are still n^2. If building from scratch that issue could be resolved.

Comment: @Saeed if you're looking to implement from scratch that paper could indeed help, but it looks like quite an undertaking.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say why you want Linear SVM, but if you can consider another model that often gives superior results then check out the hpelm python package. It can read an HDF5 file directly. You can find it here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hpelm It trains on segmented data, that can even be pre-loaded (called async) to speed up reading from slow hard disks.